# Traveling to the UK but my son can’t

Tags: uk, air-travel, dutch-citizens, lebanese-citizens

My son and I are planning to go to the UK this summer for a holiday. I have a Dutch passport; however he only has a Lebanese travel document.

Do I need to apply for a visa for him or can he just come with me without one?

Comment: Is your son eligible for Dutch citizenship?

Comment: Can you specify what the “travel document” is? Is that a passport? A refugee travel document? Something else? How old is your son?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella  yes my son i eligible i’ve applied for his dutch citizenship last year and they approved it now we just have to wait for the kings approval

Comment: @jcaron     My son has a lebanese refugee travel document, and he’s 15 years old.

Answer (score 7):

Citizens of Lebanon do need a visa to travel to the UK. Your own Dutch citizenship has no impact on the matter anymore, due to Brexit.

Answer (score 4):

Your son will need a visa by virtue of his citizenship. You can check that on the official [UK website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) and on the [IATA Travel Centre website](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/)

Note that a national identity card is not valid to [enter the UK](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk) unless the holder meets certain criteria

Comment: "Note that a national identity card is not valid to enter the UK unless the holder meets certain criteria" Or entering at the Irish land border, which Home Office's CTA policy team has confirmed to me is NOT considered an illegal entry

Comment: @Crazydre That would apply to the Dutch citizen however, based on the information given in the question (and not knowing exactly what the OP meant by ‘a Lebanese travel document’), it’s not certain it would allow a Lebanese citizen to enter via the Irish land border https://www.irishimmigration.ie/coming-to-visit-ireland/visit-ireland-travel-path/